# Error handling in extension methods

Tags: c#, exception, extension-methods

So my situation is a little more complex but this will get the point across. We'll use the typical person object.

```
public class Person()
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a List of the person object but the typical extension methods aren't enough. I would like to add my own so I create an extension class and the compiler does it's magic.

```
public static class ListExtension()
{
    public static string FullName(this Person source)
    {
         return source.FirstName + " " + source.LastName;
    }
}
```

All is well. Now I am concerned with error handling. Do I implement the error handling in the extension or by adding another extension method (I'm thinking like `TryParse()` ). For example:

```
    public static string FullName(this Person source)
    {
         if(source.FirstName == null || source.FirstName == "")
         { throw new ArgumentException("The first name is null or empty!"); }

         return source.FirstName + " " + source.LastName;
    }
```

OR

```
public static bool TryNameConcat(this Person source)
{
    bool _isSafe = false;

    if(source.FirstName != null && source.LastName != null)
    { _isSafe = true; }

    return _isSafe;
}
```

---

The implementation is very different between the two in my mind. It might make no difference in the amount of electrons / cycles etc. but one approach seems proactive and the other reactive?

> Edit:

Thank you for the great pointers and comments. As I said in the beginning my situation is more complex. I just cooked up this simple one to get the point across. Do I throw exception in my extension methods or do I proactively do a sanity check before proceeding with an operation that could error.

Comment: Why don't you just make this an instance method/property?

Comment: As an aside, you should probably use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of writing those tests out longhand.

Comment: Debug.Assert is your friend (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Rob: Actually, I'd say not - I don't want to take off the seatbelt in production. I far prefer to have sanity checks imposed with real data, not just in tests.

Comment: Might want to check if `source` is `null` before anything.

Comment: It's not clear what this really has to do with extension methods, to be honest - wouldn't you have the same decision to make in a normal instance method? Should a Person *always* have a non-empty first name and a non-empty last name? If so, and if you can edit the code of Person, then perform the validation on construction.

Comment: @JonSkeet are you suggesting we shouldn't be using Debug.Assert?

Comment: @Rob: Yup. Or at least, very rarely - only for assertions which are useful but too expensive to perform in production code. For this sort of check, I'd just throw an exception. In Noda Time I have methods similar to `Debug.Assert` of `Preconditions.CheckNotNull`, `Preconditions.CheckArgument`, `Preconditions.CheckRange` etc - but they're *always* turned on.

Comment: I just throw Debug.Assert for values I don't expect to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension method is not different from any other (static) method. It's only 'syntactic sugar' that makes it look different, but the compiler resolves it to a normal method.
Therefore, you can treat it just like any other method. In other words: throw an exception from your extension method (i.e. go with your first solution), and wrap the method call in a `try/catch`-block.

HTH Thomas

Comment: Yes and it occurred to me post submit (after reading comments and thinking more on it) that I should probably throw from the extension anyway in case a lazy developer (I'm guilty!!) goes straight to using it without the sanity check first.

Answer (score 1):

First you should question the need of extension method, why not make it an instance method to begin with.

For error checking in extension method, For your particular example, you don't have to check for null, since `string.Concat` would replace `null` with empty string. But for delimiter placement between First and Last name you will need the check.

I guess you are dealing with a different situation than simple string concatenation and if you really have to write extension methods *(and not instance method)* then extracting out functionality in extension methods only makes sense if you are going to use it independently. Like in your case  if your method `TryNameConcat` can be used independently without your method `FullName` then have the logic in extension method, otherwise don't.

Comment: I think the check is needed, since the use of delimiters should vary depending upon which fields are blank.

Comment: @supercat, yes you are right, since the OP is using `" "` as delimiter *(I missed that)*, My initial guess was that the OP is trying to avoid exception in string.Concat.

Comment: Too bad MS didn't define a string value type [whose sole field would be a `StringObject`].  In COM, which preceded .NET, empty strings were represented by null pointers, and in many contexts it makes just as much sense to have a string variable or array slot default to an empty string as to have an integer default to zero.  As it is, null strings are sometimes regarded as legitimate empty strings and sometimes cause `NullPointerException`, and there's really no rhyme or reason to it.